# "panic: strconv.ParseInt: parsing "�": invalid syntax" --> when parting int64 to convert into time

Tags: go

In a DB I have a field of type `int64` in which I store unix timestamp. Then I want to present it to the user as a normal `datetime`, as a string. However, it'll fail. Here's a simple example.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    var a int64
    a = 1658545089
    tm, err := strconv.ParseInt(string(a), 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(tm)
}
```

===>

```
panic: strconv.ParseInt: parsing "�": invalid syntax
```

What's going on here?

Comment: The error shows the string representation of what you’re parsing, which obviously isn’t a number. `string(a)` isn’t going to format the number in a string, it’s converting it as `”\xef\xbf\xbd”`

Comment: @JimB how to convert int64 into a number as is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are trying to convert int64 with string
try it with strconv.FormatInt(a, 10)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    var a int64
    a = 1658545089
    tm, err := strconv.ParseInt(strconv.FormatInt(a, 10), 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(tm)
}
```

when you try to convert an interger covering with string(), in golang it will get the corresponding ascii character
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii

after a certain interger it will only show �

Comment: you can also try it with strconv.Atoi(strconv.FormatInt(a, 10))

Comment: What'll be the difference?